# Abstract Factory Design Pattern for remote file transfer app

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-class, network-protocols

I have built a java application based on 
SSH protocol which transfers files and now I am going to extend it to protocols such as FTP, sFTP. 
Each protocol will have methods such as login, list files, and download files.

I want to with in abstract factory pattern, what is the implementation model for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to adapt to different mechanics\protocols, you can implement `Adapter pattern`. Also, adapter can be chosen at runtime, you can also implement `Factory pattern` to instantiate an adapter. And then `Strategy pattern` to have adapters and factories. All this being done with `IoC` to inject dependencies like adapters or factories